# XOR & AND equation in quantum computing ... is it correct?

Tags: quantum-cryptography

I'm trying to understand the following equality found in a paper of quantum key distribution [Fully device independent quantum key distribution](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.1810.pdf) :

$$a \oplus b = x \wedge y$$

As far as I know;

- $\oplus$ stands for lofic X-OR
- $\wedge$ stands for logic AND

Using integers from a specific set $\{0,1\}$, how the above mentioned equality can be satisfied?

Example:

- $a=1, b=1, x=1, y=1$

  $1 \oplus 1 = 0, \quad  1 \wedge 1 = 1 \quad 0 \neq 1$, therefore NOT satisfied
- $a=1, b=0, x=1, y=1$

  $1 \oplus 0 = 1, \quad  1 \wedge 1 = 1 \quad 1 = 1$ therefore satisfied

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes this and the examples are correct: depending on values of $a$, $b$, $x$, $y$, the equality $a\oplus b=x\wedge y$ is satisfied, or not.

Comment: For a second I thought you were comparing XOR to XOR... I've been programming too much in C. Yes, the examples are correct, but be careful saying that to a C programmer. In C, `^` means XOR and `&` means AND.

Comment: @Serpent27: ∧ is AND, ^ is C's XOR. Different characters, different meanings.

Comment: Yes, but they still look basically the same if you're too used to seeing only `^`

Comment: Could you add the page and line, too?

Comment: what is “lofic”?